# Custom-whitelisted indicators in wrong position on dual monitor

Tags: 11.10, unity, indicator

I just upgraded to 11.10, Unity.

I use wicd and guake so I went to dconf-editor and whitelisted these guys (well, I changed the whitelist to 'all') so their icons appear on my top panel.

However, when I switch to dual-monitor (using Nvidia's twinview), these indicators (just the whitelisted ones - not the dropbox/google reader/system load/sound/workspace ones that you can install using the repositories) move to the middle of the screen and obscure the window name in the top panel (images below).

full top panel: see how the guake/wicd icons are to the left over the window title, and all the others are over to the right where they should be (the second monitor is to the left of this screen).

[image]

Closeup:

[image]

These two (three, looks like empathy has joined the club) icons don't appear at all on the top panel on the other monitor, although the other ones that are behaving normally do.

Does anyone know how to fix this (move them back over to the right)/what further commands I can run to narrow down what the problem is?

Comment: Just to make sure it's not something else in your configuration, I would create an empty user account, whitelist those apps in it, and see if the problem occurs for that other user. If it does happen again with a fresh user account, you know it's Unity. If not, it's something in your configuration.

Comment: @Ken - thanks for the suggestion. I made a fresh user and the problem still persists (I was hoping it wouldn't!). Are there any logs I can try look into that could help?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I'd try submitting a bug to launchpad.

Comment: I have seen something similar too, it is clearly a bug and as Ken said you should submit a launchpad report.

Comment: I just found what I think may be the relevant bug: [778256](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/778256)

Comment: Aha, thank you very much for that! I'll have to find some way to get v5.2.0 of unity (my current seems to be 4.28). Or just wait for 12.04. cheers! (if you'd like to post this as an answer I'm happy to accept it)